# Angular - Same function used in many components, what's the best practice to stay DRY in this situation?

Tags: angular, standards, dry

I'm new to angular. I am building an application that has several forms - which I've created a component for each form.

Each one of these components contains the same code in ngOnInit to determine if the form is in edit mode or in create mode. I know best practice is to not repeat code, so I'm wondering what the best way to accomplish this in this situation.

Would it be just to create a service file and put the code there, then import into each of my components? That is what I planned to do but wanted to check if there is a more standard practice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create a service to do that, like this code:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UtilsService {

  constructor() { }
  sayHello(){
     return "Hello";
  }
}
```

Also... I don't know if it fits to you, but i have a component class wich i extends in a lot of pages that uses form...

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ValidatorFn, FormArray, AbstractControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
//Configs

@Component({
  selector: 'app-base-forms',
  templateUrl: './base-forms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./base-forms.component.css']
})
export class BaseFormsComponent {
  isLoading = false;

  public RegexPattern = {
    password:new RegExp(/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*=-])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,32}/),
    url:new RegExp(/[(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)/i)
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  public baseOnSubmit(form) {
    if (form.status === "VALID") {
      return true;
    } else {
      Object.keys(form.controls).forEach(field => {
        const control = form.get(field);           
        control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true }); 
        setTimeout(() => control.updateValueAndValidity(), 0);
      });
      return false;
    }
  }

  disableFields(form, msg?) {
    this.isLoading = true;
    Object.keys(form.controls).forEach(field => {
      form.get(field).disable({ onlySelf: true });
    });
  }
  disableSomeFields(form, fields: Array<string>) {
    Object.keys(form.controls).forEach(field => {
      if (fields.indexOf(field) > -1) {
        form.get(field).disable({ onlySelf: true });
      }
    });
  }

  setClassInvalid(control) {
    return !control.valid && control.touched && control.status !== 'DISABLED'
  }
  setClassValid(control) {
    return control.valid && control.touched
  }
}
```

So, here i have a lot of common form functions that i use in some cases in a project with old angular, like 7 or 9, i don't remember :D

And in the component.. (Don't forget the super inside constructor)

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { BaseFormsComponent } from 'src/app/shared/components/base-forms/base-forms.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-account',
  templateUrl: './account.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account.component.css']
})
export class AccountComponent extends BaseFormsComponent {
  editData:FormGroup;
  isSending:boolean=false;
  isBroker:boolean=true;
  constructor(
    private fb:FormBuilder
  ) {
    super();
    this.editData = this.fb.group({
      "name": ["", Validators.required]
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.disableFields(this.editData);
    this.userService.loadUser()
      .subscribe((res:DefaultReturn)=>{
        this.setFields(this.editData,res.user);
        this.enableFields(this.editData);
      });
  }

  onSubmitEditData(){
    if(this.baseOnSubmit(this.editData)){
      this.userService.updateUser(this.loginSvc.user.tUUID,this.editData.value)
        .subscribe((res:DefaultReturn)=>{
          console.log(res);
        });
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: What I suggest about RegexPattern to be set in separated file like constant and can be shared with other components

Comment: @RebaiAhmed also if i only use it in forms?

Comment: It's a recommended way for dealing with constants

Comment: Did you got my proposition ?

Comment: Yes i did, but, it will be a service to share the constants, like mine UtilsService, no?

Comment: Yeah , to be used in all the whole application